# dimension formula for fiber product of affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n, \,  Y \subset \mathbb{A}^m, \,  Z \subset \mathbb{A}^{\ell}$ be irreducible affine varieties and let $f: X \rightarrow Z, \, g: Y \rightarrow Z$ be surjective morphisms.

> **Problem:** Show that $\dim X \times_Z Y = \dim X + \dim Y - \dim Z$, where 
>   $X \times_Z Y$ is the fiber product $\left\{(a,b)\in X\times Y: \, f(a)=g(b)\right\}$.

**My proof when $Z=\mathbb{A}^d$:** The map $f$ is given by a $d$-tuple $(f_1,\dots,f_d)$ of elements of $A(X)$ and similarly $g=(g_1,\dots,g_d)$, where $g_i \in A(Y)$. 
Since $f$ is surjective, we have an injective ring homomorphism $A(Z)=k[z_1,\dots,z_d] \hookrightarrow A(X)$, given by $z_i \mapsto f_i$. Thus we can write $A(X)=k[f_1,\dots,f_d,x_1,\dots,x_s]$, where $f_1,\dots,f_d$ are algebraically independent over $k$. Similarly, we can write $A(Y)=k[g_1,\dots,g_d,y_1,\dots,y_t]$, where $g_1,\dots,g_d$ are algebraically independent over $k$. Now $A(X) \otimes_k A(Y) = k[f_1,\dots,f_d,g_1,\dots,g_d,x_1,\dots,x_s,y_1,\dots,y_t]$, with $f_1,\dots,f_d,g_1,\dots,g_d$ algebraically independent over $k$. Then 
\begin{align}
A(X \times_Z Y) &= k[f_1,\dots,f_d,g_1,\dots,g_d,x_1,\dots,x_s,y_1,\dots,y_t]/(f_1-g_1,\dots,f_d-g_d)\\&=k[f_1,\dots,f_d,x_1,\dots,x_s,y_1,\dots,y_t] = A(X) \otimes_{k} \left(A(Y)/(g_1,\dots,g_d)\right)
\end{align} and the dimension of this last ring is $\dim X+ (\dim Y - \dim Z)$.

**Question 1:** Any comments on the proof above?

**Issue with the general case:** When $Z \subset \mathbb{A}^\ell$ is any $d$-dimensional affine variety, we can write $f=(f_1,\dots,f_d,\dots,f_\ell)$, where $f_i \in A(X)$, $f_1,\dots,f_d$ are algebraically independent over $k$ and $f_{d+1},\dots,f_\ell$ are integral over $k[f_1,\dots,f_d]$. Similarly for $g=(g_1,\dots,g_d,\dots,g_\ell)$.
Now, to obtain $A(X \times_Z Y)$ we have to take the quotient of $A(X \times Y)$ by all $f_i-g_i$. This gives 
\begin{align}
A(X \times_Z Y) = k[f_1,\dots,f_d,x_1,\dots,x_s,y_1,\dots,y_t] / (f_{d+1}-g_{d+1},\dots,f_\ell - g_\ell).
\end{align} The challenge now is to show that 
\begin{align}
\dim k[f_1,\dots,f_d,x_1,\dots,x_s,y_1,\dots,y_t] = \dim \frac{k[f_1,\dots,f_d,x_1,\dots,x_s,y_1,\dots,y_t]} {(f_{d+1}-g_{d+1},\dots,f_\ell - g_\ell)}\end{align} All i know about the
$f_{d+1}-g_{d+1},\dots,f_\ell - g_\ell$ is that they are integral over 
$k[f_1,\dots,f_d,g_1,\dots,g_d]$ but this seems insufficient to show that the dimension remains unchanged.

**Question 2:** Can the algebraic argument above be adjusted to yield a proof?

**Question 3:** Is there any other, possibly more geometric, proof of the statement?

Comment: $f_i$ and $g_j$ are polynomials? (If yes, what indeterminates are you using for them: others than $x_i$ and $y_j$?)

Comment: @user26857: Thanks for the question. The $f_i$ are elements of $A(X)$, by hypothesis algebraically independent elements over $k$. So i can go ahead and take them to be part of some generators of the $k$-algebra $A(X)$. If the $f_i$ do not generate the whole $A(X)$ as $k$-algebra, then i denote the remaining generators as $x_1,\dots,x_s$. Similarly for $A(Y)$. Does this clarify my notation?

Comment: @user26857: In other words, the $f_i$ play the role of indeterminates and same for the $g_i$.

Comment: I've understood this, but I wanted to know if they are polynomials in a set of indeterminates which is disjoint from the sets $x_i$ and $y_j$.

Comment: @user26857: This set of indeterminates is $f_1,\dots,f_d,x_1,\dots,x_s$ modulo the vanishing ideal of $X$.

Comment: I think I've drawn some wrong conclusions: $x_i$ and $y_j$ are not indeterminates, just generators.

Comment: Let $d=\dim Z$. By Noether normalization theorem, there is a finite surjective morphism $Z\to A^d$. Then the composition $X\to Z\to A^d$ is surjective. If what you write is right, then $\dim X\times_{A^d}Y\le \dim X+\dim Y-d$. By magic square, $X\times_ZY\to X\times_{A^d}Y$ is a closed immersion, so $\dim X\times_ZY\le \dim X\times_{A^d}Y$. We find $\dim X\times_ZY+\dim Z\le \dim X+\dim Y$.

Comment: @Manos It seems that in your case $Z=A^d$, $s=\dim X-d$. If you really mean this, could you please explain how do you find $x_1,\dots,x_s$ when $\dim X=d$?