# Dimension of the fiber product $X\times_S Y$ of schemes over $k$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Consider two morphisms $X\to S$ and $Y\to S$ where all the schemes involved are smooth algebraic varieties over a field $k$. Is it true that
$$\dim X\times_S Y=\dim X+\dim Y-\dim S?$$

The case $S=\operatorname{Spec}k$ is well known and may be found basically in every scheme theory book. But I didn't found this more general statement even in EGA.

Comment: The statement is true when $f:X \to S$ and $g:Y \to S$ are smooth morphisms of schemes, which is perhaps the correct generalization of the result you mentioned.

Comment: Dear @PolvanHoften I eventually realised that this is what I wanted and that it was true. But I only have a very contrived proof of it. (Which uses D-modules...) Do you know a good reference for this statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that perhaps deserves to be true, but is very far from being literally true. For example, take $S$ to be any $k$-scheme and $X=Y$ to be any $k$-points.

Restricting your question to intersections, you might find the Serre intersection formula a better answer close to what you want. Further, see Toen’s ICM address about how derived algebraic geometry can help make better sense of non-transverse intersections like the one in my example.

Comment: Oh... do you know of some conditions which would make this formula true?

(I've found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359698/dimension-formula-for-fiber-product-of-affine-varieties), for example.)

Comment: This becomes a bit subtle, even for fibres of a morphism. For example, if $f\colon X\to S$ has dense image, then $f^{-1}(x)$ has dimension $\dim(X)-\dim(S)$ (and, this is nonnegative) for $x$ in some open set. I am very far from an expert, but I suspect that the formula you linked is one of very few cases where your expectation is literally correct.